# Rest api GET call doesn't return any value from the mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am trying to do a GET request for my genres in my mongoDB local database with the following code:

[image]

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Genre = require('./models/genre.js');
Application = require('./models/apps.js');

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/appstore');
var db = mongoose.connection;

// Root Call
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Please use /api/apps or /api/genres/');
});

// Get genres
app.get('/api/genres', function(request, response) {
  Genre.getGenres(function(error, genres){
    if(error){
      throw error;
    }
    response.json(genres);
  });
});

// Get apps
app.get('/api/apps', function(request, response) {
  Application.getApplications(function(error, apps){
    if(error){
      throw error;
    }
    response.json(apps);
  });
});


app.listen(28017);
console.log('Running on port 28017...');
```

In this file I am making the function that will search for all the genres in our mongoDB. Unfortunately it doesn't do this and returns me:

*localhost didn’t send any data.* and sometimes just empty rows.

Strange enough it does work for the root call (/) and will output:

*Please use /api/apps or /api/genres/*

**genre.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Genre Schema
var genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  create_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

// this is now accessible from anywhere else
var Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model('genre', genreSchema);

// Get Genres
module.exports.getGenres = function(callback, limit){
  Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

I really appreciate any help since this is my first simple REST api that I am trying to build. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**The solution apparently is using a deprecated function:**

*mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/appstore');*

**instead of:**

*mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/appstore');*